# Which Borderlands 2 DLC's are not included in GOTY edtition

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm going to buy GOTY of Borderlands 2 and as far as I know, the mentioned edition does not include all DLC's.

Which of them I should buy alone to have a 100% complete game ?

Comment: If you want all the DLC for BL2 and The Pre-Sequel, it's included in [The Handsome Collection](https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/8133/Borderlands_The_Handsome_Collection/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you buy the GOTY Edition you'd still have to buy the **Headhunter DLCs** and  the **Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack Two: Digistruct Peak Challenge DLC**.

Since a lot of other DLCs in addition of the season pass DLCs are included in the GOTY edition it's better to buy GOTY, even if you already have the base game.

**[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands_2:_GOTY_Edition)**:

> The package will contain:
>
> - The main Borderlands 2 game
> - All DLC included in the Season Pass:
>
>   - Captain Scarlett and Her Pirate's Booty
>   - Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage
>   - Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt
>   - Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep
>   - Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 1
> - Gaige the Mechromancer
> - Krieg the Psycho
> - The Heads and Skins included in the Collector's Edition
> - The Creature Slaughter Dome
> - The Gearbox Gun Pack
> - One Golden Key
> - The Vault Hunter's Relic
>
> *NOTE: The Edition will not contain any of the content released after
>   its announcement, including any Head Hunter DLCs and the Ultimate
>   Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack Two: Digistruct Peak Challenge.*

Comment: You can now get all of BL2 & The Pre-Sequel's DLC with [The Handsome Collection](https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/8133/Borderlands_The_Handsome_Collection/).

Answer (score -4):

Not true.

The stand alone packs you mentioned are about $16. All together, game of the year is $30. The season pass that includes all of it is just $30. So you would spend almost $50 to get game of the year.

If you already have the original game, why spend more instead of just spending $30 to get the season pass if you have base game?? That doesn’t make sense. Not to mention you get a free ultra HD texture pack.

Comment: The season pass doesn't include all the DLC for Borderlands 2.